# Mysql SELECT DISTINCT giving a duplicate key_distinct error

Tags: php, mysql, sql

I am running this sql on a table with around 70,000 records.  It has no increment or FK attached column to it;

```
SELECT distinct col1, col2, col3 FROM mydb.x_my_table
```

But it is producing an error;

```
Error Code: 1062. Duplicate entry '\xFF-70556-194420-15700        -col3valuehere               ' for key 'distinct_key'
```

At the start of the process this table is truncated and rebuilt using a locally loaded txt file.  I cant find the complete reference in the table at all (as a combination or singularly of the columns asked for).   Ive also tried dropping the table and creating it again - but same result.

Can anyone suggest anything?

FYI Percona, PHP-FPM, Centos Server.

Comment: You won't get `Duplicate entry` error for a `SELECT`. What's the full query?

Comment: Hi, that's what I thought, but it is happening!  That is the full query - I've just changed the col and table names.

It's being called in php like this;

    // collate and concatenate comp sku's
    $q_skus = "SELECT distinct sku,manufacturer_sku, manufacturer FROM x_manufacturer_sku";

But I've tried directly in mysql workbench (i had to add LIMIT 30000 to the end) and get the very same error

Comment: Add in the question the output of `SHOW CREATE TABLE mydb.x_my_table ;`

Answer (score 0):

Solved it with a concat.  There's no reason why the original statement didnt work as far as I can tell, but there you go.  Note I had to include the new concatenated column or it produced the same error again.

This works;

```
SELECT DISTINCT concat(sku, manufacturer_sku, manufacturer) as catcat, sku, manufacturer_sku, manufacturer FROM x_manufacturer_sku
```

Hope this helps someone else having similar problems at some point!